# Many to many relationship not returning child results

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to create what should be a very simple many to many relationship between two objects with an associative table.

EntityFramework correctly creates the associative table, but when data is populated into the tables the data being returned is always null on the join.

The relationship that I've created as outlined by the docs is as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
  //-- setup many to many relationship joins
  builder.Entity<EmployeeTrade>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.EmployeeId, x.TradeId });

  builder.Entity<EmployeeTrade>()
        .HasOne(t => t.Trade)
        .WithMany(et => et.EmployeTrades)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.TradeId);

    builder.Entity<EmployeeTrade>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Employee)
        .WithMany(et => et.EmployeTrades)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId);

  base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

And my entities look as follows:

Employee:

```
Table(name: "employees")]
public class Employee 
{
    [Key]
    [Column]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IList<EmployeeTrade> EmployeTrades { get; set; }
}
```

Trade:

```
[Table(name: "trades")]
public class Trade 
{
    [Key]
    [Column]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required]
    public decimal PayRate { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public IList<EmployeeTrade> EmployeTrades { get; set; }
}
```

For example what I have for data is as follows:

Employees:

```
Id          FirstName  LastName
----------- ---------- ---------
1           James      Dean
2           Moo        Cow
3           Herp       Derp
```

Trades:

```
Id          IsActive Name           PayRate
----------- -------- -------------- ---------
1           1        Carpenter      22.00
2           1        electrician    44.00
3           1        Plumber        55.00
```

EmployeeTrades:

```
EmployeeId  TradeId     Id
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
1           2           2
1           3           3
```

After all of this when I try to pull data out of the database for user 1, the EmployeeTrades collection is always null when it should be a collection of three objects and even then, truth be told the data returned isn't even the data I really want, which is trades.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to resolve this aside from getting the data via line query. I would hope that EF could do this heavy living for me, but from what I see this isn't the case or I'm doing something wrong that I can't seem to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default entity framework will never eagerly load indirect data (properties that are not direct fields of the table). This means you have to include `EmployeTrades` manually using the [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) function.

Comment: Ok, So this fixes that issues of null data, but the more I look at this now the more and more this looks like a very bad solution as I have a crazy circular reference. Is this really the right way to be handling a many to many, or is it a better solution to simply create the reference as needed on the fly via linq query?

Comment: Another side effect that I've noticed is that the Trade side of the relationship is always null as well and I can't quite grok why that is when the Employee side has the value I'm expecting